# ASP.NET [ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.] at bitmap.Save(MStream, ImageFormat.Tiff)

Tags: asp.net, bitmap, gdi+, tiff, memorystream

I've read hundreds of "A generic error occurred in GDI+" posts and can't quite get the issue straightened out.  I'm trying to insert a page and then apply some text to each page of a multi-page tiff.

If I just want to insert a page without applying any additional text to each page, this code has been working fine no matter how many pages the multi-page tiff contains:

```
'yada yada yada
cover.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff)
images.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream))

'loop through each page of the multi-page tif
Dim count As Integer = bitmap.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page)
            For idx As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, idx)
                bitmap.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff)
                images.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream))
            Next

'some stuff to process and save a tif
```

This is the code I'm using to insert the cover and add additional text to each page.  It seems to work fine unless the multi-page tiff has more than about 20 pages:

```
'yada yada yada
cover.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff)
images.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream))

Dim stringFormat As StringFormat = New StringFormat()
stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far

'loop through each page of the multi-page tif
Dim count As Integer = bitmap.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page)
        For idx As Integer = 0 To count - 1

            bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, idx)

            Dim bitmap2 As New Bitmap(bitmap)
            bitmap2.SetResolution(300, 300)

            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap2)

            Select Case Trim(Type)
                Case Is = "X"
                    Dim rectf As New RectangleF(2100, 75, 300, 75)
                    g.DrawString(DocNum, New Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, rectf, stringFormat)
                Case Is = "Y"
                    Dim rectf As New RectangleF(2100, 150, 300, 75)
                    g.DrawString(DocNum, New Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, rectf, stringFormat)
            End Select

            bitmap2.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff)

            images.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream))

            g.Dispose()
            bitmap2.Dispose()

        Next

'some stuff to process and save a tif
```

I get "A generic error occurred in GDI+." "[ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]" at bitmap2.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff) once I hit about the 20th image. Any thoughts as to what the issue is and how I might resolve it?  It doesn't seem to be a file permission issue.  I've tried using a "using memorystream end using" and the doesn't seem to matter.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried bringing the `Dim byteStream As New MemoryStream()` inside the loop, and properly disposing it just before the `Next`?

Comment: I adjusted my code example above.  Originally, I was using the same byteStream before I get in to the loop, for adding the cover page.  I did try a byteStream.Dispose() before getting in to the loop and then adding a Using byteStream2 As New MemoryStream() End Using and put bitmap2.Save(byteStream2, ImageFormat.Tiff) and images.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream2)) in the block.  It throws the same error at bitmap2.Save after about 20 images.  The using block should dispose of byteStream2 properly, correct?